# Running Fortran executable within Python script

Tags: python, fortran

I am writing a Python script with the following objectives:

1. Starting from current working directory, change directory to child directory 'A'
2. Make slight adjustments to a fort.4 file
3. Run a Fortran binary file (the syntax of which is `../../../../` continuing until I hit the folder containing the binary); return to 2. until my particular objective is complete, then
4. Back out of child directory to parent, then enter another child directory and return to 2. until I have iterated through all the folders in question.

The code is coming along well. I am having to rely heavily upon Python's OS module for the directory work. However, I have never had any experience a) making minor adjustments of a file using python and b) running an executable. Could you guys give me some ideas on Python modules, direct me to a similar stack source etc, or perhaps give ways that this can be accomplished? I understand this is a vague question, so please ask if you do not understand what I am asking and I will elaborate. Also, the changes I have to make to this fort.4 file are repetitive in nature; they all happen at the same position in the file.

Cheers

EDIT::
entire fort.4 file:

```
file_name           
movie1.dat       !name of a general file the binary reads
nbr_box          ! line3-8 is general info 
2
this_box
1
lrdf_bead
.true.
beadid1
C1               !this is the line I must change
beadid2
F4               !This is a second line I must change
lrdf_com
.false.
bin_width
0.04             
rcut
7
```

So really, I need to change "C1" to "C2" for example. The changes are very insignificant to make, but I must emphasize the fact that the main fortran executable reads this fort.4, as well as this movie1.dat file that I have already created. Hope this helps

Comment: To run a binary, you can use the `subprocess` module.  As for making adjustments to the `fort.4` file, that's highly dependent on the file.  Indeed, if the file is written using Fortran's "Direct" format, then it is likely going to be system-dependent.

Comment: Can this Direct format issue be circumnavigated if I write the file manipulation program in a different language, say Bash or C/C++, then call that script from my Python script? Sorry for the question but this is the first time I have ever heard of this. My advisor writes everything in Fortran, but I would like to stay current with the times.

Comment: Fortran is great -- But Direct access (particularly with unformatted files) was never standardized by compilers.  New Fortran variants provide `stream` access which behaves exactly like you'd expect regardless of the compiler..

Comment: If I understand you correctly, there is a chance I will not be able to make changes to the fortran file, is that correct? If I can automate this task, it would save countless grad student hours on something that takes an unnecessary amount of time to do by hand. Is there any resource or anything that you may have that you could pass my way regarding this issue? I am going to try really hard to overcome this issue, if possible. I know C, C++, and some Bash, if that helps at all. I would really appreciate it, and if not, thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: the file name "fort.4" says nothing about the file except that somebody was too lazy to give it a name. comments about direct access are speculative. show the open statement from the fortran code.

Comment: @zww -- It's unlikely to be as hopeless as that.  I'm just saying that the fiddling part might be tricky and (depending on the fortran code), you might need to make allowances in the python for the specific compiler dependent variations.  Alternatively, you could compile a little module to _read_ the fortran file the same way it was written using `f2py`.  As long as you're using the same compilers on the same system, you should be all set.

Comment: @agentp I am new to Fortran, and honestly, this is code I inherited from my advisor. I will make an edit containing the actual fort.4 file I am manipulating, although I am not sure that will help you guys decide anything. From my limited understanding of what his code does, the pre-compiled, fortran executables extract relevant and necessary information from fort.4. In essence, my job is to make changes to fort.4, then run this executable. Again, I'll put more info in an edit to my original post.

Comment: Additionally, thanks @mgilson so much for your help I will look into this library!

Comment: ok, seeing as its a plain text file, the fact that the source code for the executable is fortran (or whatever) is not important.  What is important is knowing where the executable expects to find its input. We might guess its looking in its current directory.(?)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so there is a few important things here, first we need to be able to manage our cwd, for that we will use the os module

```
import os
```

whenever a method operates on a folder it is important to change directories into the folder and back to the parent folder. This can also be achieved with the os module.

```
def operateOnFolder(folder):
     os.chdir(folder)
     ...
     os.chdir("..")
```

Now we need to do some method for each directory, that comes with this,

```
for k in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(k):
    operateOnFolder(k)
```

Finally in order to operate on some preexisting FORTRAN file we can use the builtin file operators.

```
fileSource = open("someFile.f","r")
fileText = fileSource.read()
fileSource.close()
fileLines = fileText.split("\n")
# change a line in the file with -> fileLines[42] = "the 42nd line"
fileText = "\n".join(fileLines)
fileOutput = open("someFile.f","w")
fileOutput.write(fileText)
```

You can create and run your executable `output.fx` from `source.f90`::

```
subprocess.call(["gfortran","-o","output.fx","source.f90"])#create
subprocess.call(["output.fx"])                             #execute
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! One thing though: I am not sure this makes a difference in what you are saying, but to run the fortran binary, I do not need to invoke the command 'gfortran -o' etc. On the contrary, I need to run the already compiled code by using the standard

Comment: 'a.out'. command or '../../../' whereever the binary is located. Can subprocess perform these actions? I really appreciate your file manipulation input!

Comment: Nevermind, that is a naiive question. I understand my mistake, I will try subprocess. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I don't mean to blow up you update feed, but I just wanted to let you know I tried the subprocess command in order to run the binary, and it worked. You have no idea how happy this makes me, thanks man.

Comment: By the by you can put a relative directory into the subprocess.call as long as the address points to the file you want to run from the python runtime cwd (`os.getcwd()`). for example if your executable was in the parent directory of the parent directory of your current directory, you could do,  `subprocess.call(["../../a.out"])`

Comment: `subprocess` is a good starting point. Depending on your needs, you can extend your automation with `multiprocessing` without much additional coding. I've built a simple batch queuing system for running hundreds of Fortran jobs, keeping a multi-CPU machine fully utilized without overloading it. It's been a godsend for software testing and running many multi-hour production jobs overnight.

Comment: i don't see in the question anything that would indicate he needs to compile the source code.

Comment: `os.chdir()` especially as used here is a bad idea.  It changes process global state.  If there is something going wrong between the two `cd()` calls and the second call is skipped because of an exception, the process is in a wrong state and all further code operates on an unexpected working directory. Also if `folder` is not just a name of a folder in the current working directory the second `cd()` does not return to the correct folder. The function can't be called concurrently or recursively.

Comment: @BlackJack so what you're saying is they should just bury their head in sand and cry because while there is in obvious path from a to b  you think it might take them to c and therefor they should just stay at a? I'm sorry I just don't like it when people invent problems without presenting solutions.

Comment: @kpie Just don't use `os.chdir()`. Work with absolute and/or relative paths with the functions from `os.path` instead.  For `subprocess` the `cwd` argument may come in handy to change the working directory of the started process.

Comment: I understand your point especially for final cuts in production but for rapid prototyping and development I have found `os.chdir()` to be useful. You defiantly have good insight, I'll certainly remember it next time I have to reach around the file tree!